# two java sdks in one system

Tags: java, intellij, openjdk

I installed java using the `sudo apt install openjdk-17-headless-jdk` but for some reason my intellij IDEA community edition couldn't find the jdk when I tried to create a maven project.

Since it was an emergency I selected the download jdk option and downloaded the
`Oracle open jdk-17.0.1` version.

I would like to know if this would cause any issues in the future or not.

Since I selected 17.0.1 from the intellij options so I already know the version. But when I typed `java --version` it gave me:

```
➜  ~ java --version                                 
openjdk 17 2021-09-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17+35-Ubuntu-1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-Ubuntu-1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**Note:** Even before installing Intellij I checked if java installed correctly. It was working perfectly fine.

I also tried:

```
➜  ~ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

But unfortunately when I tried to locate the jdk in intellij and navigated to the `/usr/bin` I only saw a lots of `x11` marked folder.

[image]

Using terminal when I navigated to `/usr/bin` I couldn't find the `/java` folder.

**N.B:** I'm logged in as root if that information is needed

I would like to know if there is anything I can do to check the different sdks and what can I do to clear up the situation.

Comment: `/usr/bin/java` is not a directory (which Microsoft calls a folder to cause misunderstanding and confusion); it _could_ be a file but is more likely a link to `/etc/alternatives/java` which in turn is a link to something like `/usr/lib/jvm/{someversion}/bin/java` (which is a file). The java runtime -- and JDK, which is not just the runtime -- used by Intellij doesn't have to be the same as the one used from commandline, so checking commandline doesn't really tell you anything relevant.

Comment: I'm a bit confused sorry. So in this situation do I have to do anything to solve this 'problem' or is this not a problem at all?